# House warm thermostat off

Tags: heating

I have an old house that has baseboard heating. Ranch house. It has a full basement the length of the house. New Lochinvar boiler. Thermostat is off and yet our side of the house is warm. 62-66 degrees even in winter with thermostat off. Is it possible, pipes under the floor are heating my side of the house because of 1"-1 1/2 carrier pipes?

Comment: " my side of the house" - Are you sharing the house? Does this imply two thermostats?

Comment: How is this system piped? Diverter-tee? Two-pipe? Something more zoned-ish?  Does the baseboard have zone valves or thermostatic radiator valves controlling it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! It sounds as if you probably have the answer to your question. The boiler is on your side of the house. The heat supply lines run under the floor on your side. Depending on how well insulated the lines and your floors are you're probably benefiting or sweltering in the heat your tenant is calling for when they crank up the thermostat.
If the basement isn't finished it should be fairly easy to determine - but I'm guessing it is.